How to connected React application to Zoho CRM with internal hosting feature
I have to connect my react application which is basically a widget for ZOHO CRM, I have connected it with external hosting feature and its working but my team wants to connect it with internal hosting. I have tried so many ways but nothing is working.
I try to copy the files in build folder and past them in app folder of widget and pack it with zet pack command still its doesn't work.
I tried to write script to create a zip file in react application its self but it also doesn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
